# I want to join 2 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I am trying to join two tables and getting an error I can't resolve.

```
var result = _context.FileModels
  .Join(_context.FilesMetaData,
  fm => fm.Id,
  fmd => fmd,
  (a, b) => new
  {
      fmId = a.Id,
      fmds = b
  });

return result;
```

---

This is the error message: [image]

These are the models:

```
 public class FilesMetaData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid FileId { get; set; }
        public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string OtherData { get; set; }
        public string AppUser { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
enter code here
```

and FileModels are some random columns that have one index.

Comment: Fix up your database entity classes, and the join will be done for you.   I find, the main reason for using `.Join` is that you don't have foreign keys set up properly in your database.

Comment: I have a FK(FileModels) in FilesMetaData

Comment: It looks like you are using EntityFramework.   Database first or code first?

Comment: I am using code first.

Comment: Relationships are made through navigation properties in EF. You should not be performing joins but eager loading instead (if desired)

Comment: What is the FK on FilesMetaData? fmd.FileModelId perhaps?

Comment: Yes, its FileModelId.

Answer (score 0):

Your join is missing a column:

```
.Join(_context.FilesMetaData,
  fm => fm.Id,
  fmd => fmd.FileModelId,  // <--- Define the right column
```

Comment: @Ryuzake Can you post your classes then, because something else is wrong...

Comment: @Ryuzake this is probably going to go down a dark path, but double check your dbsets in your context, maybe hop over to Chat. Something isn't set up right, and without all the code It's hard to see the issue, and changes the scope of the question considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have foreign keys but where are the navigation properties?

I would expect to see something like:

```
public class FilesMetaData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public File File {get;set;} <-- Navigation Property
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }
    public Application Application {get;set;} <-- Navigation Property
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class File
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    ...
}
public class Application
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

This will automatically do the joins when required.

Comment: It was IntelliSense that bugged... I solved the question.